Unable to Compile Go Code with SQLite Dependencies in Nix Flake Shell
I have a simple Nix Flake shell with the SQLite dependencies required to access the database, but I am unable to compile the code due to the following error:
go build -o foo cmd/main.go
# runtime/cgo
flag provided but not defined: -E
Go is a tool for managing Go source code.

Usage:

    go <command> [arguments]

{
  description = "PoC";

  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs";
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

    gomod2nix = {
      url = "github:tweag/gomod2nix";
      inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
      inputs.utils.follows = "utils";
    };
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils, gomod2nix }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let
        pkgs = import nixpkgs {
          inherit system;
          overlays = [ gomod2nix.overlays.default ];
        };
      in
      {
        packages = {
          default = pkgs.gnumake;
        };
        formatter = pkgs.nixpkgs-fmt;

        devShell = pkgs.mkShell {
          buildInputs = with pkgs; [
            gnumake
            gcc
            glibc.dev

            go
            gopls
            gotools
            go-tools
            gomod2nix.packages.${system}.default
            golangci-lint
            protobuf3_20
          ];
          buildPhase = "make";
          shellHook = ''
            export CGO_ENABLED=1

            export PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
            make dep
          '';
        };
      }
    );
}

you can find a reproducible here https://codeberg.org/vincenzopalazzo/go-nix

I've cloned your repo and can successfully run nix develop --command go build -o foo cmd/main.go? How are you running it?

I am running it nix develop --command make and I can compile ok with your command but not ok with mine. Do you know why?

Sounds like a potential problem with the Makefile then, you should debug that.

The make file is really simple and it is just calling the go command https://codeberg.org/vincenzopalazzo/go-nix/src/branch/main/Makefile#L9 Do you think that the bug is here? if yes, why I get a go toolchain error?

I don't know. But you should probably close this question and reopen a new one for your makefile / make command.

Make sense, thanks!

Posting this answer just because this can be useful for someone else that it is trying the same thing that I am doing.
We found a possible problem with this.
I usually wrap all my build logic inside a Makefile, so inside the comment a user noted that the following command was working nix develop --command go build -o foo cmd/main.go
but the same command inside the Makefile was throwing the error, so this issue is solved because the nix flake is working as expected.
