Unable to Compile Go Code with SQLite Dependencies in Nix Flake Shell when using a Makefile
I usually wrap all my build logic inside a Makefile, so inside the comment a user noted that the following command was working nix develop --command go build -o foo cmd/main.go
However, when I run the make file I get the following error
$ make
go build -o foo cmd/main.go
# runtime/cgo
flag provided but not defined: -E
Go is a tool for managing Go source code.

Usage:

    go <command> [arguments]

The specific target that the Makefile is using is the following one:
CC=go
FMT=gofmt
NAME=go-nix
BASE_DIR=/script
OS=linux
ARCH=386
ARM=

default: fmt
    $(CC) build -o $(NAME) cmd/main.go

fmt:
    $(CC) fmt ./...

A minimal reproducible example is in there https://codeberg.org/vincenzopalazzo/go-nix

It's not the source of your problem (probably), but CC=go is very bad form.  make's built-in rules expect $(CC) to expand to the the name of a C compiler, which go is not.  It would be easy and more appropriate for your purpose to just use a different variable.  I've seen GO used for such purposes, for example, though this doesn't have the same weight of standardization and convention that CC for a C compiler does.

Anyway, what happens if you run the command go build -o foo cmd/main.go from the command line?  Supposing that you get the same result (which is likely), the issue is probably with the go command in this environment, not with make or your makefile.  Perhaps you need some kind of shell configuration that nix develop provides, but that is not automatically set in your default shell environment.

@JohnBollinger See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79062271/unable-to-compile-go-code-with-sqlite-dependencies-in-nix-flake-shell

I'm sorry, but what am I supposed to see there that is relevant and not already presented here?  If in fact there is any such thing, then it should be edited into this question.

Additional question, though: what does the command type go tell you?

[vincent@vincenzopalazzo-arch-dev ocean-liquidity-market]$ type go go is /nix/store/chzgk756zb2cqlzbjr86m0lfxi63cdfy-go-1.22.7/bin/go
